# How to change visibility of image in data template?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have an image that is inside of a datatemplate and I want to be able to set its visibility. The code looks something like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dvm:TaskViewModel}">
....
<Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="2">
                            <Image  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Margin="8,0,10,0"
                                    Style="{StaticResource ActionImage}"
                                    cal:Message.AvailabilityEffect="Disable"
                                    cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseUp] = [Action RunTaskNow($DataContext)]"
                                    Source="..\..\Resources\Images\export.png"
                                    Visibility="{Binding CanRunTasks, Converter={StaticResource boolToCollapsed}}">
                            </Image>
                        </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

CanRunTasks is a boolean property that is in the viewmodel behind, but is not in the TaskViewModel that represents the data template datatype.

Comment: What is the "viewmodel behind"? You are saying it is in the view model but not in the TaskViewModel. So in which view model is it?

Comment: Well, the user control that contains this data template has a different view model then the one that the data template uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this issue this way:

**a)** Access the parent controls datacontext and the Property you want to access:

```
Visibility="{Binding DataContext.CanRunTask, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type <PARENTCONTROL>}}}"
```

where PARENTCONTROL is the control that uses your DataTemplate

or:

**b)** if you are creating your VMs in CodeBehind you can inject your ParentViewModel into the child viewModel 
e.g.

```
   TaskViewModel tvm = new TaskViewModel(ParentViewModel parent)

    ....
```

in TaskViewModel:

```
public ParentViewModel Parent
{
    get{ return _parent;}
}
```

in XAML:

```
Visibility="{Binding Parent.CanRunTask
```